# How to split TextBox in Winforms

Tags: c#, sql-server, winforms

I am trying to make a query to the database for this I use a textbox where I must place values that are always greater than 1, that's why the in is, but I need to be able to add a quote 'at the beginning and at the end of each line also adding the comma, in each line or how could I do it since currently I can only add quotes at the beginning and end but of all the text and the comma if also at the end

```
    SELECT TOP(500)  [contenido]
                FROM[Clientes].[dbo].[web]
      where sitios in ('https://www.google.com','https://www.youtube.com')
```

In the database it generates the following

```
contenido   - sitios
multimedia  - https://www.youtube.com
informacion - https://www.google.com
```

but in the query by the app for not having the quotation mark ' and the comma gives an error

```
SELECT TOP(500)  [contenido]
                FROM[Clientes].[dbo].[web]
      where sitios in ('https://www.google.comhttps://www.youtube.com')

error
```

this is my code

```
     new SqlDataAdapter(new SqlCommand(@"
SELECT TOP(500)  [contenido]
            FROM[Clientes].[dbo].[web]
  where sitios in ('"+textBox1.Text+"')", conexion.conectado())).Fill(dataTable);
```

[image: debug]

Comment: Use SQL Parameters to avoid SQL injection and your formatting issues.

Comment: im new in this and not get acces to modify the bd only search how that ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Can you try this ?

```
        var urlList = textBox1.Text.Split(
             new[] { "\r\n", "\r", "\n" },
            StringSplitOptions.None);

        string query = "SELECT TOP(500) FROM[Clientes].[dbo].[web] WHERE sitios in ({0})";
        SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(query, conexion.conectado());

        int index = 0;

        List<string> paramList = new List<string>();
        foreach (var url in urlList)
        {
            if (!String.IsNullOrEmpty(url))
            {
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@param" + index, url);
                paramList.Add("@param" + index);
                index++;
            }
        }

        cmd.CommandText = String.Format(query, String.Join(",", paramList));
        cmd.CommandTimeout = 99999;
        new SqlDataAdapter(cmd).Fill(dataTable);
```

This method will solve your problem and be safer than your code.

Comment: who use @param1? i try and get this in debug code ('https://www.google.comhttps://www.youtube.com') @param1 = ' not cant get ('https://www.google.com','https://www.youtube.com')

Comment: @ryuzdev You would need two parameters for that